# How to initialize each row of a 8x10 matrix with the right shifted value of the previous row

Tags: c

So what I'm trying to do is have the first row of the 8 x 10 matrix say 12345678910. The second line would say 10123456789. The third would say 91012345678. Ect. This is what I have so far. It just continues to count up.

```
#include<stdio.h>


#define ROWS 8
#define COLS 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int A[ROWS][COLS];
    int B[COLS][ROWS];
    int x,y;


    for (x=0; x<ROWS; x++)
    {
        for (y=0; y<COLS; y++)
        {
            A[x][y] = 1*x + y;
        }
    }


    printf("=== Original matrix === \n");

    for (x=0; x<ROWS; x++)
    {
        for (y=0; y<COLS; y++)
        {
            printf("%3d  ", A[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just fill the first row with whatever you want in it.  For example, for numbers counting up from zero:

```
for (y = 0; y < COLS; y++)
  A[0][y] = y;
```

Once you have the first row filled, this will fill the remaining rows as you described (each row right-rotated by one from the previous row):

```
for (x = 1; x < ROWS; x++)
  for (y = 0; y < COLS; y++)
    A[x][(x + y) % COLS] = A[0][y];
```

The above starts filling from the second row (index of 1) onward, and always copies values from the first row.  However, the position in the current row it copies to is offset by the row number, so it starts one place later for each row.  The `%` operator is used to wrap the index back around to the start of the row when it gets to the end.

Comment: a more intuitive solution would be `A[x][y] = A[0][(x + y) % COLS]`

Comment: @Suryavanshi going from `A[x][(x + y) % COLS] = A[0][y]` to `A[x][y] = A[0][(x + y) % COLS]` reverses the shift direction, though.

Comment: correct solution would be `A[x][y] = A[0][(abs(COLS+y-x)) %COLS];` which is unnecessarily expensive in computation

Comment: its not, thats what I was saying. For clarification of others.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not following your logic in the line

```
    A[x][y] = 1*x + y;
```

I seem to have gotten closer using `%`:

```
        A[x][y] = (1+x + y) % 10;
```

This takes the remainder of the sum of `x` and `y` when divided by 10 - which, if we start with 1 rather than 0, begins to approach what you want.  It's not exactly correct, but it's a start.

```
=== Original matrix === 
  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0  
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0    1  
  3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0    1    2  
  4    5    6    7    8    9    0    1    2    3  
  5    6    7    8    9    0    1    2    3    4  
  6    7    8    9    0    1    2    3    4    5  
  7    8    9    0    1    2    3    4    5    6  
  8    9    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 8
#define COLS 10

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int A[ROWS][COLS];
    int B[COLS][ROWS];
    int x,y;
    for (x=0; x<ROWS; x++) {
        for (y=0; y<COLS; y++) {
            A[x][y] = (1+x + y) % 10;
        }
    }
    printf("=== Original matrix === \n");
    for (x=0; x<ROWS; x++) {
        for (y=0; y<COLS; y++) {
            printf("%3d  ", A[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
  }
}
```